# No windows insider option in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-insider, windows-11

I recently read that it would be better to switch from dev to the beta channel. But I can't find the windows insider option on the settings page.

[image]

The **error encountered** message in the image has nothing to do with the insider option. I still couldn't find the insider option when there was no error. I am running Windows 11 build 22000.168

Comment: Could the computer be in the scope of this report on Ars Technica: [Old PCs are getting booted out of the Windows 11 Insider Preview](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/09/old-pcs-are-getting-booted-out-of-the-windows-11-insider-preview/)?

Comment: @Jared - Are you in the Beta or Developer channel? 22000.176 is the current Beta and Release Preview channel build, while 22449 is the current Developer (RS_PRERELEASE) channel build. My suggestion would be is to download a 22449 ISO and upgrade your installation that way. Instead of submitting a comment, you should edit your question to provide any additional information. You could also download 22000.176 although I suspect your inability to install updates is indeed linked to your current Insider Preview status.  It's not clear your machine is currently enrolled.

Comment: I signed up for the dev channel, but now I can't check that since I don't have the option for windows insider option in the settings page